# how to replace url pattern with correspond variable?

Tags: javascript, regex

`const userId = 123;
const userName = 'john'
let url = '/foo/:userId/:userName'`

how to generate a result string like this `/foo/123/john`
It seems that str.replace(reg, callback) does not work

Comment: And how do you use `.replace`?

Comment: Check [string templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) with ES6 features.

Comment: @Justinas 
`let userId = 123;let userName = 'bar';let url = '/foo/:userId/:userName';
    m = /(:[a-zA-Z]*)/g.exec(url)
    if (m) {
        url.replace(/(:[a-zA-Z]*)/, `${m[1].substr(1)}`)
    }`
output is "/foo/userId/:userName"

Answer (score 0):

`replace(reg, callback)` definitely works, you probably haven't used it correctly.

Here is an example:

```js
const userId = 123;
const userName = 'john'
const params = {userId, userName}
let url = '/foo/:userId/:userName'
url = url.replace(/:[^\/]+/g, (g) => (params[g.substr(1)]))
console.log(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use string interpolation if your code can allow you to do it this way

```js
const userId = 123;
const userName = 'john'
const url = `/foo/${userId}/${userName}`;

console.log(url);
```